# passing 2 parameters in restler

Tags: php, restler, swagger, swagger-php

I'm trying to pass an object and a string to the function and test it in restler,
but I'm getting this error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request: `user` is required but missing."
  },
```

in the documentation I wrote:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param User $user user object
 * 
 * @param string $lang the language of the name e.g. "en" or "ar". 
 * 
 * @url POST /login/
*/
```

and this is the function:

```
public static function login(User $user,$lang) {
    ....
}
```

I'm using the pre-last version of restler.

Answer (score 0):

In Restler 3, required parameters are sent via the URL, such as /login/myuser, so the URL has to include that parameter (sending a request to just /login will return that error).